# Is the ATtiny85 actually used in any consumer electronics?

Tags: embedded, attiny, attiny85

I was wondering if anyone here knows of any products that utilize the ATtiny85. It appears to me that it's solely used by makers/electronics enthusiasts. I'm asking because I think it would be interesting to see to what products its limited IO and storage can be applied. Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask a question like this - I couldn't find a more applicable SE site.

Comment: Uhh I've seen an attiny 13 low power in the remote control handle of a Dyson vacuum cleaner. I doubt they're that rare, just that they're used for simpler applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Is that surprising?

no.

Why?

Because Atmel can't care at all about a couple thousand hobbyists buying a couple thousand low-cost chips per month. What they aim at with low-cost chip is mass-produced low-cost devices, selling millions of chips instead. Most products in this world need some microcontroller logic, but not much. You really don't need much IO or RAM to make a microwave oven beep. Or to control the charging in a electric toothbrush. Or to set up the sequence in which to start the power supplies inside a complex product¹.

Of course the hobbyist market creates visibility and allows to sell a couple products that are profitable in small numbers; but really, in the greater scheme of things, hobbyists can't sustain a large semiconductor manufacturer.

---

¹ fun fact, doing power sequencing is something very often done by a microcontroller reserved for that purpose only – you just can't turn on your complex main MCU before power runs. And that's pretty much the upper limit of what an Attiny85 can do – a bit of I²C and a bit of voltage/ADC math, and the memory's full. With a well-known environment to rapidly write down the firmware for that, plus competetive prices, especially for the non-DIP form factors, why not go ATTiny? I hate 'em, personally, but if you're more used to Atmel than to 8051...

Comment: Ah, Marcus, I once did a whole 10-channel drink dispenser with LCD and user menu on a single ATtiny plus some I/O expanders. It's possible and it's fun but it's just a bit outdated to do so nowadays.

Comment: @Janka I personally know someone who "inherited" a LiIon charge/power sequencing/monitoring/I²C slave/master ATtiny85 device,who had to go in and rewrite the whole thing in assembler just to get things down to *exactly* the program memory size(not a byte left),and he was very cranky about that.I don't think it's "outdated" per se – it's just that for me,an Attiny85(512B RAM/512B EEPROM/10b ADC/20MHz CPU clock/0.6mA at4MHz idle,no sensible sleep modes)costs around 91–110ct;for that amount of money…MKL02Z Cortex M0+(4kB/32kB/12b/48MHz/0.2mA+sleep modes)is just the more economically sound choice.

Comment: @Janka … considering that the ease of programming a device with kBs of RAM and default integer sizes that just are sufficient for 99% of problems is a big time saver (don't get me started on interrupt handling, memory mapping, and toolchain advantages of ARMs); the thing that really does speak for the ATTiny is its 5V IO capability – but I nowadays really rarely need that.

Comment: The thing that really speaks for the ATtiny series is you are actually able to program it in assembler. Sometimes it's better not to trust any sufficiently advanced toolchain.

Comment: @Janka with all due respect, Atmels assembly is fugly. That's ugly with an additional F as in WTF. You can program any processor in assembly, and personally, I'd choose Thumb over AVR core ISA any day.

Comment: The question is: do you? No, you don't. You rely on the toolchain. Do you at least check the disassembly? Do you *understand* from the disassembly what the µC does? That's why a small, simple design as the ATtiny is still a choice for simple but critical applications.

Comment: @Janka yes, I do. And unlike the AVR toolchain, I can trust my toolchain pretty far when compiling C. I do occasionally check assembly when it makes sense.

Comment: So. You rely on the toolchain and *occasionally* check assembly. That's okay but proves my point. I would just use simple assembly for a critical application and help myself by picking a µC without bells and whistles. For anything else, I just pick a SoC with Linux on it. (Yeah, I'm lazy.)

Comment: he, @Janka, we're both lazy :) I just like my microcontroller to come with good C support and have a word width that fulfills most of my needs; I'd assume you're simply much more experienced with writing assembler than I am; writing C just works faster for me, and frankly, I trust my compiler more than I trust my assembly for anything that is more complex than an ISR that toggles an output :) so, yeah, maybe we're just not working on the same complexity levels :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is the ATtiny85 actually used in any consumer electronics?
>
> It appears to me that it's solely used by makers/electronics enthusiasts.

Outside of consumer electronics and enthusiasts markets, there is a huge universe out there. The fact you only see them in one tiny segment doesn't mean they aren't used in other places. I have used them to process buttons, and as data aggregators in industrial control projects.

Answer (score 2):

The ATTINY85 is used in Dame Product's flagship FIN product...

[image]
https://www.dameproducts.com/products/fin

It handles the user interaction, motor control, and battery monitoring.

The A/D converter, internal voltage reference, extremely low power sleep with wake on pin, and ability to direct drive LEDs, small physical size, wide supply voltage range, deep & wide supply chain availability, and low cost make it perfect for products like this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55391/discussion-on-answer-by-bigjosh-is-the-attiny85-actually-used-in-any-consumer-el).

Answer (score 1):

I had to repair an automatic car battery tender ([Car battery tender)](http://www.oreillyauto.com/site/c/detail/BTD0/0210123/N0360.oap?ck=Search_N0360_BTD_-1_-1&mn=Battery%20Tender&mc=BTD&pt=N0360&ppt=C0005) and it had an ATtiny in an 8-pin package - I can't remember which family member.

I'm sure they, and similar devices, are used in billions of products these days wherever a small amount of control or intelligence is required; remote controls, thermostats etc.  The market for those far outweighs that of hobbyists.

Its capabilities are limited but it is very cheap to build into a product.